# Adding a slidedown effect to a slider counter in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, slick.js

I am using Slick.Js to show slides on my page and I have a slide counter with the code below that shows the current slide number with the total slides. I am trying to achieve a feature where the current slides number slides down when the slide is changed. Below is the code that displays the slide counter:

```
var $status = $('.carousel-counter');
var $slickElement = $('.project-carousel');

$slickElement.on('init reInit afterChange', function (event, slick, currentSlide, nextSlide) {
    //currentSlide is undefined on init -- set it to 0 in this case (currentSlide is 0 based)
    var i = (currentSlide ? currentSlide : 0) + 1;
    $status.html( '<span class="current_slide">' + i + '</span> / <span class="total_slides"> ' + slick.slideCount + '</span>');

});
```

[Working fiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/jtf05ez3/3/)

Comment: `"I am trying to achieve a feature where the current slides number slides down"` - slides down where/how? Do you have an example of what you're looking for?

Comment: @user7290573 When the slide changes, the counter should change from 1 to 2 to 3 and so on. When the number 1 to changed 2 , 2 should slide down in place of 1 in the counter.

Comment: Sounds like you want some kind of "odometer" effect - example library here: https://github.hubspot.com/odometer/

Comment: yes something like that

Comment: @user7290573 so something like this https://jsfiddle.net/DwXUX/25/